# Where is the Migration state table in the DB for Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, database-migration

I can't see the table in the list of tables in my DB. I can't find any config file in my project to store the database version state. How does it know what version my database is on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my current experience it has gone into one of two places in SSMS:

1. Regular Tables node
2. System Tables node - A sub folder in your regular table listing

The table is called `__MigrationHistory`